# Firestore Query slow on empty collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Below is the start of my code for a firebase function. It gets to the "oncreate" log statement in less than 2 seconds.  It takes almost 2 minutes to get to the "got snapshot" log statement.  The Invitation collection does not exist, it has zero documents.  Why is running a query on an empty collection take so long and how do I speed this up? Thanks in advance.

```
exports.register = functions.firestore.document("Users/{Email}").onCreate(
async (snap, context) => {
  // see if Invitation exists, if yes get FamilyId from there
  const collectionRef = admin.firestore().collection("Invitations");
  functions.logger.info("oncreate", {structuredData: true});
  collectionRef.where("Email", "==", snap.id)
      .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        functions.logger.info("got snapshot", {structuredData: true});
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          addUser(snap);
          return;
        } ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're performing an asynchronous operation in the Cloud Functions code, you need to return a promise from the top level of your code so that the Cloud Functions container knows how long to keep it running.

From the code you shared, that means you need to add a `return` here:

```
return collectionRef.where("Email", "==", snap.id)
  ...
```

I recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), which explains more about how to deal with asynchronous calls.

Comment: In addition to Frank's anwser, I would add that 1/ You should preferably not mix-up `async` with `then()`. Do `const querySnapshot = await collectionRef.where("Email", "==", snap.id).get();`. 2/ If the `addUser()` function is asynchronous (e.g. it writes to Firestore) you should also call it with `await`.